# How to display content under the current line in a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building a small snippet to show references inside a text.

Basically i makes a reference like (Nielsen, 1999) expand when clicked.
Right now it breaks the line when expanding.

I want the expanded reference to show under the line of text.

EDIT (to explain my intended solution a bit more in detail)

When the text is expand I don't want the expanded box to float above existing text. I also don't want it to expand inside the flow of the text. It needs to be positioned inside it's own box.

I've tried searching for a way to maybe append the .reference-expand at the end of a current line. But I couldn't find any solutions.

Picture added to clarify:

[image]

How can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var allFootnotes = $('.reference-inline');
  allFootnotes.each(expandReference);

  function expandReference() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      $(this).closest('.reference').find('.reference-expand').toggleClass('active');
    })
  }
});
```

```css
.reference-inline {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.reference-expand {
  display: none;
  padding: .8rem;
  margin: .8rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.reference-expand.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<span class="reference"><span class="reference-inline"> (Nielsen, 1999)</span><span class="reference-expand"><strong>Nielsen, Jørn (1999):</strong> This is the title and all the other stuff about the publication.</span></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: Position it absolutely.

Comment: Basically what you are wanting is a tooltip.

Comment: @jeff Not exactly. I might not have described my need explicitly enough then. My fault. A tooltip is (as I understand it) floating above the text as is also suggested below in Answers. I still want the text to display in a box underneath the current line. And pushing underlying lines down. I just wanted a solution where it didn't break the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can amend the CSS of the reference to be positioned absolutely, so that it is taken out of document flow and does not break the line containing it.

Also note that you can simplify the jQuery code you're using too, by just providing the logic to `on('click')` directly, and removing the function:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.reference-inline').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.reference').find('.reference-expand').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.reference-inline {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.reference-expand {
  display: none;
  padding: .8rem;
  margin: .8rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.reference-expand.active {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff0;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<span class="reference"><span class="reference-inline"> (Nielsen, 1999)</span>
  <span class="reference-expand"><strong>Nielsen, Jørn (1999):</strong> This is the title and all the other stuff about the publication.</span>
  </span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
  irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: I might not have been clear enough in my description. I'm looking for a solution, where the expanded reference is not floating above the text in this tooltip-manner of style.

So that it still displays on it's own line right beneath the current line. Just without breaking the line.

Comment: That's still not clear. I can't envision how you expect it to be on the line below, without floating, and without breaking the line. Could you add an image of what you expect this to look like to the question

Comment: Yes. I've added a picture to my question above :)

Comment: Right, now I understand what you mean. That's going to be incredibly hard to do, as HTML elements do not count line breaks as their own entities when positioning elements. To get this to work you'll need a method of knowing where the current line ends, and the next starts which will involve delving in to nodes. This is far from simple. I'd strongly suggest you use tooltips instead.

Comment: Yearh. I suspected that. I just thought it would make for a nice interface design animating in the expanded reference :) I'll go with a neat designed tooltip for now. And then this will forever cringe in the back of my head ;)

Answer (score 1):

You set `.active` span as display: block. Set `inline/inline-block` instead.

```
.reference-expand.active {display: inline;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided with an example of "tooltips" style of reference popup

**Edit:** This is just a concept of how to handle this, it doesn't check for cases like near corner etc

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var allFootnotes = $('.reference-inline');
    allFootnotes.each(expandReference);

    function expandReference() {
        $(this).on('click', function(event) {
            var elRef = $(this).closest('.reference').find('.reference-expand');
            elRef.css({ top: event.pageY, left: event.pageX });
            elRef.toggleClass('active');
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.reference-inline {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.reference-expand {
    display: none;
    padding: .8rem;
    margin: .8rem;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.reference-expand.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<span class="reference"><span class="reference-inline"> (Nielsen, 1999)</span><span class="reference-expand"><strong>Nielsen, Jørn (1999):</strong> This is the title and all the other stuff about the publication.</span></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: I guess my description of the intended solution wasn't clear enough.

I still want the expanded span to show in a box and not float above the text.

The trouble is that in my current solution the line of text is broken, when there is a refence. And I really want that line to appear as before expanding. While the expanded reference is still showing below the current line.

Comment: I don't think this is easy because you wouldn't know which part of the text is wrapped. It will required dynamically loaded contents so javascript can parse the text and do all the calculation behind the scene